# Woocommerce order created webhook firing only sometimes and with incomplete payload

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I've set up a WooCommerce webhook that fires when an order is created, but I've found that the webhook only fires sometimes, and even when it does fire, it often contains incomplete body data, meaning that instead of the full json structure of the order, the payload only contains "webhook_id xxx" (where xxx is the webhook id number value).

I've been testing by creating orders and setting the webhook Delivery URL to a `hookbin.com` temporary bin.

In the cases where the webhook fires but contains incomplete data, nothing gets written to the Webhook Log on the WooCommerce webhook settings pages. The only way that I know that it fired is by refreshing the hookbin and seeing the request go through.

In the rare cases where the webhook does fire with the complete json data of the order, the Webhook Log is updated.

How should I go about debugging this?

Comment: I have exact same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: I didn't. The problem was in my dev environment and production didn't have that problem. I'm still interested to know.

Comment: Thank you @fortuneRice I did not notice that it is actually working with my production environment.
My dev environment is hosted on a private network with a fake DNS (that I change with /etc/hosts) in order to have same DNS for prod and dev. Maybe this is the reason

Comment: I came across the same situation when only a webhook_id=<<id>>
 was posted as payload. As stated in the docs, i think this is the so called 'ping' to the Delivery URL. But in my case it is triggered everytime the webhook is saved (not only the first time) in the backend in WooCommerce.

Docs: Note: On the first time your webhook is saved with the Activated status will be sent a ping to the Delivery URL. (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/)